# SFDC Report showing wrong currency

Tags: salesforce, currency

I have custom Currency field in custom object. I am storing some currency value in this.
when I display it in report, it is showing correct value but name of currency displayed is incorrect. 
For example `AED 0.64` but it should display `EUR 0.64`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom `currency__c` (picklist?) reports aren't aware of that. All fields of type "Currency" will continue to be displayed with record's "true" currency (`CurrencyIsoCode` field). This behavior is consistent on standard page layouts, VF pages (as long as `<apex:outputField>` was used and on reports so I doubt you've realized it only when you reached the point of making reports.

If you see "AED 0.64" it means `CurrencyIsoCode` is AED. You can flip the report to € using Show (menu bar next to where you select charts) -> Currencies using -> EUR. This will however convert values using your current exchange rates. And you'll have to drop to the report "My Currency Field (converted)" instead of regular "My Currency Field").

If you want "raw" values - store them in a field of type Number and not Currency? You won't be able to change type of standard fields though...

I don't think we can help you more without knowing why you decided yo need a custom currency field and why you didn't explore limitations like that.